# WebView в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, webview

В `CardView` у `RecyclerView` присутствует `WebView`, при тестировании обычным текстом (*вместо WebView был TextView*) все летало даже на самых слабых моделях аппаратов, стоило заменить `TextView` на `WebView` - стало подтормаживать даже на относительно мощных. Можно как-то облегчить вывод (как я понимаю множества `WebView`) в `RecyclerView`?

Comment: почему стали использовать WebView вместо TextView? что грузится в WebView?

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych туда прогружается текст с html-тегами, источник в виде json уже содержит html-теги.

Comment: такой вариант вас не устроит?
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych выглядит аналогично - правда пока в данных всего 1 сообщение, ближе к выходным появится сотня, протестирую под нагрузкой. Огромная благодарность за помощь - отпишите ваш вариант как ответ, чтобы я мог принять его как правильный.

Comment: ок, сейчас сделаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте TextView для отображения Html текста слудующим образом

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Descrip‌​tion here</p>"));
```